# Concatenate lists with Python

Tags: list, concatenation

I would like to concatenate two lists:

```
list_a = ["hello", "world"]
list_b = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

and get something like this as output:

```
list_c = ["hello a", "hello b", "hello c", "hello d", "world a", "world b", "world c", "world d"]
```

The second list is basically going from a to z and create combinations with the list_a.

Comment: Not every routine/function/method/operator/keyword has a tag. Please choose tags from a list & read their wikis. Tag [tag:join] is for the relational DB operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce

list_a = ["hello", "world"]
list_b = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

def cross_join_lists(word):
    return [f'{word} {letter}' for letter in list_b]

def concat_lists(final_list, a_list):
    return final_list + a_list

joined_lists = list(map(cross_join_lists, list_a))
list_c = reduce(concat_lists, joined_lists)

print(list_c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [f"{i} {j}" for i in list_a for j in list_b]

# output: ['hello a', 'hello b', 'hello c', 'hello d', 'world a', 'world b', 
          'world c', 'world d']
```